# I want recommendations about which CMS to go for where should I ask it

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a developer seeking recommendations for an open source CMS.  I had an age old question on SO with 20+ upvotes asking for recommendations for a book but it was recently deleted for being off topic.  I then asked for my CMS recommendation question on programmers and was told recommendations are off topic but there are other places on stack exchange i could ask it.  I know the basis of SE sites is questions and answers and discussions are discourage but I would like some feedback from the development community about what they have used and that fits my specific requirements.  I am not looking for a discusion or a which is best or to start a forum style thread.  I just want "I have used this it has the following features you have requested, I have also found these other features useful.

Bearing in mind i want to know from a developer's point of view, is there a place on SE that I can ask this kind of question and if so where.

Comment: Stack Exchange, for the most part, does not accept recommendation questions.  You can try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but read [this post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) very carefully before posting your question there.

Answer (score 4):

Ask here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Please read this before asking a question on there though. 
[What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Some key points from there

**Content**

> The content provided in the question needs to clearly identify the use
>   case for the software. What are you going to do with it? What is it
>   for? How are you going to use it? These are all important questions
>   and I feel that these should be required for a question to be on topic
>   here, to reduce ambiguity and ensure that this doesn't just devolve
>   into a guessing game.

**What features must the application have?**

> Tell us what the software has to be capable of doing and we will
>   recommend software that does it.

**Feature requirements should be listed in order of importance**

> Every question should contain a list of features in order to keep the
>   scope of the question from becoming too broad. These should be listed
>   in order of importance from "must have" down to "these are optional
>   but would be nice".